# USA phone number validation when USA selected from country dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have two fields, one is country dropdown and other is phone number field, I want to validate US phone number format when user select the USA from the country drop-down. right now I am just validating phone number for 10 digits but I want to validate for countries 
I am using Asp.Net core MVC. here are my code and design.
please help if any suggestions.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label country-code">@Label.ContactNumber</label>
        <select asp-for="CountryId"
                class="code-control form-control"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofCountry, "Id", "CountryWithPhoneCode"))"></select>
        <input asp-for="PhoneNo" class="code-control form-control" id="txtContactNumber" placeholder="@Label.ContactNumber" onkeypress="return Carver.Organization.onTxtContactNumberKeyPress(event);" />
        <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNo" class="text-danger"></span>

        <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
        <input asp-for="TenantId" type="hidden" />

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the question, have you tried and have issues?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the question is, I want to apply the validation for US-based phone numbers when the US is selected in the drop-down. the issue is I don't know how to apply it using data annotations.